# How to place a div below header/navigation bar in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to place a `div` just below the **navigation bar.** The width of the div must be same as the width of the wordpress theme. This div comes above the Posts and the **Sidebar**, just likes ads below navigation bars are placed.

I have tried `get_header` and `loop_start`. `get_header` places the div at the top, even before the **Site Name** is printed. `loop_start` though prints it below the navigation bar, **overlaps** it with the **sidebar**.

Is there any **theme independent wordpress api (tag)** that can be hooked to acheive this?

I know that theme files can be edited but this would mean editing all the themes I install. So I don't want to do it.

I want to do this on **Multisite Install.**

Thank you..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Answering my own question ...**

The function `get_header()` is defined in **wp-includes/general-template.php.** Placing 
`echo '<div> My content </div>';` or as **@IanB** mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645247/how-to-place-a-hook-to-execute-after-header-in-wordpress/#9645318), `<?php include 'div_template.php'; ?>`  at the end of this function definition solved my problem.

modifying this function has an **advantage** and a **disadvantage...** The **advantage** is that each and every theme need not be tweaked to acheive this because `get_headers()` is theme independent, and the **disadvantage** is that this modification we made, will get deleted when wordpress is updated to a newer version.

**Still thanks for all the replies...**

**Peace...**

Answer (score 2):

you can use  `add_action(loop_start,smtg)` or  `add_action(loop_end,smtg)` or `apply_filters('the_content', $content);`

like :

```
<?php
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = do_your_stuff;
?>
```

it really depends on what you want to do ...
see more here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

all the "above - below - overlap" are not really relevante - they are CSS specific..
But if you really want to do so - you can always use REGEX on the content...

or another method - for example :

```
function k99_replace_content(){

//get the content   
$content= get_the_content(); //get the content as a variable

// where we want to cut ??
// by length ??
$full_length= STRLEN($content);
$cutting_point = ($full_length/ 2);
// regex ??
//do regex stuff here ..

// clip off the first part - if we choose by length
$firstpart = SUBSTR($content, 0, $cutting_point);

//  ending '<br>' 
$end_point = STRRPOS($firstpart, '<br>');

// add whatever

return SUBSTR($content, 0, $end_point) . "<div>put whatever you want>/div>" . SUBSTR($content, $end_point); 
}
```

add_filter('the_content', 'k99_replace_content');

or the last option, use what @IanB suggested together with one of these method - and include through a filter ..

Answer (score 1):

Make a file with your div html info, save it as div_template.php and upload via ftp to your theme file.

Then, put this code below the nav bar code:

```
<?php include('div_template.php'); ?>
```

This will dynamically add your div html code wherever you want to put it.

Try it out!

Comment: I know this would surely work... But I don't want to edit theme files ... For a multisite, I have to do this for every theme install... This is why I was trying to develop a plugin... I want a theme independent solution...